# How can the element that an event is attached to be determined in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Assuming I have a button element with a child element inside of it. If I add an `onClick` event to the button and then click the child, the event.target will be the child. How is it possible to find the element that has the click handler (in this case the button)?

The code below is a simplified example of the problem, in my app I have a few levels of nesting so using `parentElement` wont suffice.

```js
const Button = (
  <button
      class="outer"
      onClick={() => console.log(event.target)}>
    <span class="inner"></span>
  </button>
);

ReactDOM.render(Button, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.inner {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hmm, where does `event` variable come from, because it it not passed from the listener? How is it optional, because it still magically works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `currentTarget` instead of `target`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the property `currentTarget`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

What MDN says:

> The currentTarget read-only property of the Event interface identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to Event.target, which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant.